# How to replicate/copy a diagram? In R-statistics.

Tags: r, plot

I have country-year data that I want to present in a diagram. 
Each country in the dataset received a number of X's and Y's.

This is how the dataset looks like (simplified):

```
Country     Year    X  Star Stop  Y   
Afghanistan 1997    0   0   0     0   
Afghanistan 1999    1   0   2     0   
Afghanistan 2000    0   0   3     0   
Afghanistan 2001    1   0   4     0   
Afghanistan 2007    0   0   9     1   
Afghanistan 2008    1   0   10    0   
.
Brazil      1995    1   0   11    0   
Brazil      1994    1   0   12    0   
Brazil      2012    1   0   13    1   
Brazil      2013    0   0   14    0
```

So what I want to do is to make a diagram (below I give an example) for some states in the dataset that would 1) show a number of X's  (x axis) and Y's (y axis), like the picture below, and 2) a diagram with X's (on the x axis) and years (y axis).

All suggestions are welcome – thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: Hi @Pascal, I saw your comment and will soon publish my attempts. I have started with histogram but it is not the same really.